# Run Yahoo Messenger in multiple instances

Tags: windows, yahoo-messenger, multiple-instances

We can do this with previous version of Yahoo Messenger (here is how-to). But with the latest version, same method cannot be applied. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I have the solution [here](http://namgivu.wordpress.com/2010/11/16/run-multiple-instances-of-yahoo-messenger-by-tweaking-windows-registry/)

Summary:

- Run `regedit`
- Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Yahoo\pager\Test
- Add new value `plural`, details:
- Right click on the right pane, then New – DWORD
- Rename it to `plural`
- Update `plural` value to 2, details:
- Double click it
- Enter 2 in `Data` box
- Select `Heximal` radio in Base box
- Close `regedit` program.
- Done

Hope this helps!

Comment: Shortcut: `reg add HKCU\Software\Yahoo\Pager\Test /v plural /t REG_DWORD /d 2` through Command Prompt

Comment: Also, you have to choose the base (hex vs decimal) _before_ entering your data.