# how to run multiple instances of yahoo messenger?

Tags: windows, yahoo-messenger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run Yahoo Messenger in multiple instances](https://superuser.com/questions/211417/run-yahoo-messenger-in-multiple-instances)

I want to run multiple Yahoo Messenger instances for different user on the same machine. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: http://www.johntp.com/2006/07/10/how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-yahoo-messenger-8/

Comment: Or this http://techcruser.blogspot.com/2007/04/run-multiple-yahoo-messenger.html

Comment: @JonH: You can edit your comment no need to write comments separately.

Comment: @Harry Joy - true but it doesn't cost me any money!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to edit the registry. Go to following location on registry

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Yahoo/pager/Test`

Then `Right click > create DWORD` > name it `“Plural”` and change the value `0` to `1`.

However, this will allow you to run the same messenger version multiple times. For example, You can't have a US messenger running in parallel with an messenger version for india.